# Excel Pivot Table - Display first item from the list in Summary field

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I need to display text in summary field. Lets say I have 3 columns, `Supplier Name, Month, ChequeNo, and Amount`. I setup Supplier Name and Month  in `Row Labels`. And it is showing me the Amounts in expected way. But I also want to add `ChequeNo` as a regular field, means it should not display as sub-group (or with indentation). Because in one month, each supplier could have only one ChequeNo.

Is there any way to do it? May be like, if there could be some function like First() which could let me display the `ChequeNo` in the list without further indentation.

Comment: unfortunately excel doesn't have `First` aggregate as Access queries does, but you can look into Power Query or Microsoft Query

Comment: Thanks @Slai for suggesting another option. It would be more helpful, if we can know how to use PowerQuery with Pivot Table.

Comment: Pretty much the same way we learn how to use anything else - search (online), try, and optionally ask someone when stuck. There isn't enough specific information for a good answer such as Excel version, is VBA preferred, sample input and desired output, etc. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9cUYpXIKsU

Comment: I am not even sure if you can use Power Query with PivotTable, but there is [Power Pivot](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Power-Pivot-Add-in-a9c2c6e2-cc49-4976-a7d7-40896795d045)

Comment: That's really nice feature. I will give it a try.